# Block public access to expressjs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firewall

Consider, the following expressjs app:

```
var express = require('express');
var http    = require('http');
var httpApp = express();

httpApp.configure(function() {
    httpApp.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static/'));
});

var server = http.createServer(httpApp).listen(4444);
```

now,
i want this server not to be available publically & **ONLY** to respond to requests from specific clients based on their IP address/domain. Everybody else should get `403 - Forbidden` error.

I searched the API Doc & found way to do this to first enable trust proxy by `app.enable('trust proxy')` & then check `req.ip`.

However, I can't I access `req` object. so if anyone take this code & can show me how deny a req based on its IP/domain, that would be super-helpful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply add a piece of middleware that checks the IP and denies access if it doesn't match:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (allowed(req.ip))
    next();
  else
    res.status(403).end('forbidden');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use express-ipfilter

**Installation**

```
npm install express-ipfilter
```

**Usage with Express**

```
var express = require('express')
    , ipfilter = require('express-ipfilter')
    , app = express.createServer()
    ;

// Whitelist the following IPs 
var ips = ['127.0.0.1'];

// Create the server 
app.use(ipfilter(ips, {mode: 'allow'}));
app.listen(3000);
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ipfilter#installation

Answer (score 0):

I had to tweak @Jilo-Paulose's solution a little bit in my case:

```js
const express = require('express');
const ipfilter = require('express-ipfilter');

express()
    .use(ipfilter.IpFilter(['127.0.0.1','::1'], {'mode': 'allow'}))
    .use(express.static('static'))
    .listen(3000);
```